# Excel Search within text issues

Tags: excel, search, text

This is what I have been using and it works perfectly fine when only 1 cell is defined.

```
=IFERROR(SEARCH($K$2,C2),"")
```

The above returns a result when using vlookup but I want the Within_Text to be searching across C2:E2.

When I change it to

```
=IFERROR(SEARCH($K$2,C2:E2),"") and I search for something that is in C2:E2 I don't get any results.
```

The vlookup I am using is this:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(J3,A2:E200,{3,4,5}, FALSE),"")
```

The purpose of this is to be searching 3 columns that are comprised of full name, specialty and department and I want to be able to search any of the columns and for it to return the 3 fields for each person. (if that makes sense).

Comment: Generally, if functions only want 1 cell but I have more, I create a new column that concatenates the data from the columns in question and use that in the function

Comment: mcalex - Thank you! The concatenates function worked a charm.
pnuts - The reason why filter wasn't suitable is that there are quite a few different bits of information and I wanted a centralized point to display the information that is being searched

Comment: mcalex how do I mark this as answered? I'm happy with what you provided as a response and has made my spread sheet function how I want it to.

Comment: Thanks pnuts. Cannot believe how quickly the replies came through :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Excel functions where the function requires only one cell but your data is in a range (or non-contiguous cells), the trick can sometimes be to organise that data that into a single cell.

This can be done with the concatenate function as:

```
=concatenate(b2, c2, e2)
```

If you want the concatenated data to be human readable try something like:

```
=concatenate(b2, " ", c2, " ", e2)
```

This way, Excel can use the data you need the way it wants.

Comment: Again thanks for your help. 

The data didn't have to be readable as I already had the information sorted into a list that was. 

Ended up with this...

=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(J3,A2:E200,3, FALSE),"")
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(J3,A2:E200,4, FALSE),"")
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(J3,A2:E200,5, FALSE),"")

That sorted the required information into 3 separate columns and from concatenating I can search any word/partial word that I need.

Really happy :D

Comment: I use the pipe character as a delimiter because it's infrequently used. `=concatenate(b2, "|", c2, "|", e2)` It's still human readable, too.